# Sum of prime numbers below 2000000?

Tags: c++, sum, primes

How do i find the sum of all primes below 2 million? Project Euler 10th question, http://projecteuler.net/problem=10.
I tested my code for below 10 and works like a charm. But below 2 million does not seem to work :/ It has been about 15 minutes and still going, I don't think it should take that long, Right? I'll try the sum function but I still don't get why this isn't working?

EDIT: I figured I can't use the sum function as the numbers don't even get stored in the array :/

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x,y,z=0,s[200000],a,sum=0;
    bool isprime;
    for(x=3;x<2000000;x++)
    {
        for(y=2;y<x;y++)
        {
            if(x%y!=0 && x!=y)
            {
                isprime =true;
            }
            else
            {
                isprime =false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isprime ==true)
        {
                s[z] = x;
                z++;
                isprime = false;
        }
    }
    cout<<z;
    for(a=0;a<z;a++)
    {
        sum=sum+s[a];
        cout<<"Sum is being calculated "<<sum<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"The sum is "<<sum+2<<" LADIES";
}
```

Comment: What processor are you running this on? And what compiler are you using? Do you really need to use "long long" for your variables?

Comment: Are you sure that there are less than 200000 primes under 2 million? Couldn't you use an `std::vector<unsigned long long> v` instead of a fixed size array, and use `v.push_back(x)` ... `sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end());`

Comment: @Benoit There are.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+primes+below+2000000

Comment: @Tom: he is adding 2 to the final sum (last line)

Comment: Processor - Intel Core i3-370M clocked at 2.40 GHz
The default compiler that came with Code::Blocks...

Comment: You are looping on average 1000000 times within a loop of 2000000 .. that gives 2000000000000 times in the inner loop. That does take some time. Try with something between 10 and 2000000, to get an idea on how much time it would take

Comment: Ok, so assuming you don't want to go to 2 billion or more, using `long` instead of `long long` for the variables in your loop should speed things up by a fair amount. You can also quadruple your loop by trying only odd numbers for primes, and only trying to divide by odd numbers (and 2).

Comment: It would take quite some time but would Benoit's approach make it noticeably faster?

Comment: Implement the sieve of Eratosthenes -- it will solve this problem in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Sieve is fine for 2M numbers. I have a simple prime number calculator that I wrote for a different purpose. It calculates (using a single processor) primes up to 2M in 1.3s or so on my Ahtlon64 machine (using sqrt to limit the inner loop, and only checking odd numbers, otherwise the same as the posted code here). The very naive approach similar to the one used above is still not finished from when I set it off pretty much immediately after seeing this question. So, clearly the problem is largely due to running MANY more inner loops than ncessary (and double outers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your program will check for too many unnecessary divisors.

In order to check that a given integer is a prime, you need to check that it has no divisor lesser or equal to its square root. Because, if there was a divisor greater than the square root, the quotient would be an integer, and would be lesser than the square root.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x,y,z=0,s[200000],a,sum=0;
    bool isprime;
    for(x=3;x<2000000;x++)
    {
        for(y=2; y*y <= x ;y++)
        {
            if(x%y!=0 && x!=y)
            {
                isprime =true;
            }
            else
            {
                isprime =false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isprime ==true)
        {
                s[z] = x;
                z++;
                isprime = false;
        }
    }
    cout<<z;
    for(a=0;a<z;a++)
    {
        sum=sum+s[a];
        cout<<"Sum is being calculated "<<sum<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"The sum is "<<sum+2<<" LADIES";
```

You could use a vector instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x,y;
    std::vector<unsigned long long> primes;
    bool isprime = true;

    for(x=3; x<2000000; x++)
    {
        isprime = true;
        for(y=2; y*y <= x ;y++)
        {
            if(x%y==0 || x==y)
            {
                isprime=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isprime)
        {
            primes.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    unsigned long long sum = 2 + std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout<<"The sum is "<<sum<<" LADIES";
}
```

Comment: You can speed it up further, since you're maintaining a vector of primes, you can simply use that vector to test later numbers.  Rather than test every divisor < sqrt(x).

Comment: @Rohanchrome: instead of `for(y=2; y*y <= x` use `for(std::vector<unsigned long long>::const_iterator y = v.begin(); (*y)*(*y) <= x && y != v.end(); ++y)` and use `*y` instead of `y`

Comment: But the result is not the answer in Project Euler - 
The sum is 1179908154 LADIES
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3128.886 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: the first code is just **buggy**; both contain superfluous computations; both implement **sub-optimal** trial division.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple and fast if you use a sieve:

```
function sumPrimes(n)
    sum := 0
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n step 1
        if sieve[p]
            sum := sum + p
            for i from p * p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
    return sum
```

Should take only a second or two to run.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to sum primes up to and including 'n' I came up with the following solution. I hope you find it easy to follow:

```
function sumPrimes(num) {

  // determine if a number is prime
  function isPrime(n) {
    if (n === 2) return true;
    if (n === 3) return true;
    if (n % 2 === 0) return false;
    if (n % 3 === 0) return false;

    var  i = 5;
    var  w = 2;
    while (i * i <= n) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        i += w;
        w = 6 - w;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // subtract 1 for 'not being prime' in my context
  var sum = isPrime(num) ? num - 1 : -1;

  for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    if (isPrime(x) === true) {
      sum += x;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Maxima, I could generate all the primes raised to powers
Here is a sample:

```
factor(product(i,i,2000000,2001000));
2^1005*3^499*5^255*7^169*11^101*13^83*17^61*19^54*23^46*29^36,,,,,2000939*2000941*2000953*2000959*2000963*2000969*2000989
```

Then I tried to abstract the radicals and add them together.
I think it may work if you are paitent enough.  It will take a long time!!!

Comment: can you please elaborate bit more?

Comment: "sum" is not "product".